# Add or Update data in Checkbox + Radiobutton Visual basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio

Okay, this is my problem; I have code like this:

```
Private Sub process_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles hitung.Click
    If radiobuttonplus.Checked = True Then
        Me.h1.Text = Val(txt1.Text) + Val(txt5.Text)
        Me.h2.Text = Val(txt2.Text) + Val(txt6.Text)
        Me.h3.Text = Val(txt3.Text) + Val(txt7.Text)
        Me.h4.Text = Val(txt4.Text) + Val(txt8.Text)
        result = (h1.Text * h4.Text) - (h2.Text * h3.Text)
        resultdeterminan.Text = result

   ElseIf checkboxadjoint.Checked = True Then
        Me.a1.Text = 1 * (Val(Me.h4.Text))
        Me.a2.Text = -1 * (Val(Me.h3.Text))
        Me.a3.Text = -1 * (Val(Me.h2.Text))
        Me.a4.Text = 1 * (Val(Me.h1.Text))
        result = (a1.Text * a4.Text) - (a2.Text * a3.Text)
        resultdeterminan.Text = result
        resultadjoint.Text = result
    End if
End Sub
```

As you can see, `radiobuttonplus` has data underneath it and `checkbuttonadjoint` also has data below it.

I use `checkbuttonadjoint` to update data from `radiobuttonplus`.

Initially, there were no problems regarding `radiobuttonplus`, because I tried to successfully display all the data in `radiobuttonplus`; however, the problem arose when I clicked `radiobutton` + ticked `checkbuttonadjoint`. The data in `checkbuttonadjoint` is not displayed and does not update the data from `radiobuttonplus`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `ElseIf`, when the first `If` is executed the second block will never be executed. If you want both to execute then change `ElseIf` to simply `If`. You'll need to add an `End If` before that to close off the first block.

So when you're all done, it'd look like this:

```
Private Sub process_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles hitung.Click
    If radiobuttonplus.Checked = True Then
        Me.h1.Text = Val(txt1.Text) + Val(txt5.Text)
        Me.h2.Text = Val(txt2.Text) + Val(txt6.Text)
        Me.h3.Text = Val(txt3.Text) + Val(txt7.Text)
        Me.h4.Text = Val(txt4.Text) + Val(txt8.Text)
        result = (h1.Text * h4.Text) - (h2.Text * h3.Text)
        resultdeterminan.Text = result
   End If
   If checkboxadjoint.Checked = True Then
        Me.a1.Text = 1 * (Val(Me.h4.Text))
        Me.a2.Text = -1 * (Val(Me.h3.Text))
        Me.a3.Text = -1 * (Val(Me.h2.Text))
        Me.a4.Text = 1 * (Val(Me.h1.Text))
        result = (a1.Text * a4.Text) - (a2.Text * a3.Text)
        resultdeterminan.Text = result
        resultadjoint.Text = result
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does mean you could have the CheckBox code run when it is checked and the RadioButton is not.  They could both run separately and independently.  Is this a valid possibility for your app?

Comment: if I run checkbox only then the code runs but if I run radiobutton and checkbox then the code in the checkbox doesn't run. error in placing the if statement